How do I find the smallest circle that can enclose a polygon?
Using python, how do I find the smallest circle that can enclose a polygon?
A polygon is defined as a set of coordinates that map the vertices inside a 2D plane.
Guidelines:
Input: A list of tuples representing the coordinates of the polygon’s vertices.  For example, [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)].  Numpy, pandas, GeoPandas etc may also be sensible input options.
Output: Coordinates of the center of the smallest enclosing circle and its radius.  For instance, as a tuple: ((x_center, y_center), radius).  Output can be anything reasonable: list, dict, object attributes etc.
Constraints:
The algorithm should efficiently handle a reasonable number of vertices.  Take 100 vertices as an upper limit.  Finding the convex hull of the vertices will help.
Example:
For an input square with vertices [(2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)], the output should be ((1.0, 1.0), 1.4142).
They're guidelines.  I don't want to be overly proscriptive.
You can refer to existing algorithms, source libraries or software packages for finding the minimum bounding circle, but the implementation should be in Python.
This is known as the smallest circle problem.

@nayuki has implemented a variant of Welzl’s algorithm in python linked from https://www.nayuki.io/page/smallest-enclosing-circle

With opencv, this is very straightforward using the minEnclosingCircle :
import cv2
import numpy as np

def mec(vertices):
    return cv2.minEnclosingCircle(np.array(vertices))

mec([(2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]) # ((1.0, 1.0), 1.414313554763794)


Testing some random polygons :


Here is an answer using cvxpy and scipy.
By default, this finds a circle that encloses a square.  There are options for generating regular polygons (specifying number of points and radius) or random points (specifying number of points, minimum and maximum coordinates).
SciPy is used to find the convex hull of the polygon points.  This transforms concave polygons into convex polygons.
import sys
import math
import random

import cvxpy as cp
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull


def get_convex_hull(vertices_set):
    '''
    Compute the convex hull of the polygon.

    The convex hull of a set of points is the smallest convex set that
    contains all of the points.  The convex hull of a concave polygon contains
    fewer vertices than the original polygon.  This should reduce cvxpy
    constraints and run time for concave polygons with many vertices.

    Uses scipy.ConvexHull.

    :param vertices_set: Set of (x, y) tuples representing the polygon vertices
    :return: hull_vertices Set of (x, y) tuples representing the convex hull
                           of the polygon vertices
    '''

    # Convert set to list for ConvexHull function.
    vertices = list(vertices_set)
    vertices_len = len(vertices)

    # Compute the convex hull of the polygon.
    hull = ConvexHull(vertices)

    # Extract convex hull vertices.
    hull_vertices = [vertices[hull_vertex] for hull_vertex in hull.vertices]
    hull_vertices_set = set(hull_vertices)
    hull_vertices_len = len(hull_vertices_set)
    # print('Convex hull vertices:', hull_vertices_set)

    # Warn about vertex removal.
    if hull_vertices_len < vertices_len:
        vertices_diff = vertices_len - hull_vertices_len
        print(f'Warning - convex hull calculation removes {vertices_diff} vertices:')
        print('\t', vertices_set - hull_vertices_set)

    return hull_vertices_set


def check_vertices(vertices):
    '''
    Check vertices for problems.

    Must be at least 3 vertices.
    Vertices must all be tuples.
    Vertices must all be 2 dimensional.

    :param vertices: Set of (x, y) tuples representing the polygon vertices
    '''

    # Must be at least 3 vertices.
    if len(vertices) < 3:
        print('Must be at least 3 vertices:', vertices)
        sys.exit()

    # Vertices must all be tuples.
    if not all(isinstance(vertex, tuple) for vertex in vertices):
        print('Vertices must all be tuples:', vertices)
        sys.exit()

    # Vertices must all be 2 dimensional.
    vertex_sizes = [len(p) for p in vertices]

    if not all(vertex_size == 2 for vertex_size in vertex_sizes):
        vertex_size_min = min(vertex_sizes)
        vertex_size_max = max(vertex_sizes)
        print('Vertices must be 2 dimensional:', vertices)
        print('Vertex sizes:', vertex_sizes)
        print(f'Vertex size - min, max: {vertex_size_min}, {vertex_size_max}')
        sys.exit()


def minimum_enclosing_circle(vertices):
    '''
    Find minimum enclosing circle for a polygon.

    Uses cvxpy with Euclidean distance constraints.
    Euclidean distance from each vertex to the circle center should be
    less than or equal to circle radius.
    The cvxpy objective is to minimise the enclosing circle radius.

    :param vertices: Set of (x, y) tuples representing the polygon vertices
    :return: Center (x, y) and radius of the minimal enclosing circle
    '''

    # Variables for the center of the circle (c_x, c_y) and the radius.
    center = cp.Variable(2)
    radius = cp.Variable(nonneg=True)

    # Objective: Minimize the radius.
    objective = cp.Minimize(radius)

    # Constraints:
    # Euclidean distance from each vertex to the center should be <= radius
    # cp.hstack - Horizontal concatenation of arguments
    # cp.norm - Euclidean distance
    constraints = [cp.norm(cp.hstack(vertex - center), 2) <= radius
                   for vertex in vertices]

    # Formulate the problem.
    problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

    # Solve the problem.
    problem.solve()

    # Check problem status.
    if problem.status != cp.OPTIMAL:
        print('Solver failed to find a solution')
        sys.exit()

    # Return the center coordinates and the radius.
    return center.value, radius.value


def describe_circle(center, radius):
    '''
    Print circle position and radius.

    :param center: Center (x, y) coordinates of the minimal enclosing circle
    :param radius: Radius of the minimal enclosing circle
    '''

    (c_x, c_y) = center
    print(f'Circle center: ({c_x:.4f}, {c_y:.4f})')
    print(f'Circle radius: {radius:.4f}')


def get_vertices(num_points=5, radius=None, min_coord=None, max_coord=None):
    '''
    Either  
    1) generate regular polygon centered on origin  
    2) generate random points
    3) return hardcoded square (the default).

    A polygon is defined as a set of coordinates that map the vertices
    inside a 2D plane.

    :param num_points: number of points
    :param radius: radius
    :param min_coord: minimum coordinate
    :param max_coord: maximum coordinate
    :return: Set of tuples containing 2D coordinates
    '''

    if radius is not None:
        # Generate regular polygon centered on origin.
        vertices = generate_regular_polygon(num_points, radius)
    elif min_coord is not None and max_coord is not None:
        # Generate set of random 2D tuples.
        vertices = generate_random_points(num_points, min_coord, max_coord)
    else:
        # Return hardcoded vertices of square.
        vertices = {(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)}
        print('Hardcoded polygon:', vertices)

    return vertices


def main():
    '''
    Standard main function.

    Get hardcoded square vertices or 
    generate a regular polygon centered on origin or 
    generate random points on 2D plane.
    Check for problems with vertices.
    Calculate convex hull of vertices.
    Find the minimal enclosing circle of the convex hull.
    Describe the minimal enclosing circle.
    '''
    # There are 3 options for generating a set of vertices
    # 1) Generate a regular polygon centered on origin
    #    vertices = get_vertices(num_points=5, radius=5)
    # 2) Generate random points on a 2D plane
    #    vertices = get_vertices(num_points=5, min_coord=0, max_coord=10)
    # 3) Return hardcoded square vertices (the default)
    vertices = get_vertices()

    # Check for problems with points/vertices.
    check_vertices(vertices)

    # Calculate convex hull of the points/vertices with scipy.
    convex_hull = get_convex_hull(vertices)

    # Find the minimal enclosing circle of the convex hull with cvxpy.
    cen, rad = minimum_enclosing_circle(convex_hull)

    # Print description of minimal enclosing circle.
    describe_circle(cen, rad)


def generate_regular_polygon(num_points, radius):
    '''
    Generates coordinates of a regular polygon centered on the origin.

    :param num_points: number of points
    :param radius: radius
    :return: Set of tuples containing 2D coordinates of regular polygon
    '''

    # Sanity check parameters.
    assert isinstance(radius, int)
    assert isinstance(num_points, int)
    assert radius > 0
    assert num_points >= 3

    # Generate regular polygon centered on origin.
    regular_coords = []
    angle = 2 * math.pi / num_points
    for i in range(num_points):
        # coords or tuples containing x, y coordinates
        coords = (radius * math.cos(i * angle), radius * math.sin(i * angle))
        regular_coords.append(coords)

    # Convert list to set.
    regular_coords_set = set(regular_coords)
    print('Generated regular polygon:', regular_coords_set)

    return regular_coords_set


def generate_random_points(num_points, min_coord, max_coord):
    '''
    Generates at least 3 random 2D points for testing.

    A set of n random points may not result in an n-sided polygon.

    :param num_points: number of points
    :param min_coord: minimum coordinate
    :param max_coord: maximum coordinate
    :return: Set of tuples containing random integer 2D coordinates
    '''

    # Sanity check parameters.
    assert isinstance(min_coord, int)
    assert isinstance(max_coord, int)
    assert isinstance(num_points, int)
    assert num_points >= 3
    assert min_coord < max_coord

    # Generate random 2D integer points.
    random_coords = []
    for _ in range(num_points):
        # coords or tuples containing random integer coordinates
        coords = (random.randint(min_coord, max_coord),
                  random.randint(min_coord, max_coord))
        random_coords.append(coords)

    # Convert list to set.
    random_coords_set = set(random_coords)
    print('Generated random 2D integer points:', random_coords_set)

    return random_coords_set


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Call main function.
    main()

For the default square, this returns:
Hardcoded polygon: {(2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)}
Circle center: (1.0000, 1.0000)
Circle radius: 1.4142

CVXPY may be overpowered for this problem.  Anecdotally, this solution is quite slow.
For testing purposes, the script provides 3 options:

return hardcoded square vertices

this is the default


generate regular polygons centered on the origin

requires a radius parameter to get_vertices function
optionally requires num_points - defaults to 5


generate random points on 2D plane

requires min_coord and max_coord of square 2D plane to get_vertices function
optionally requires num_points - defaults to 5



The get_vertices call must be edited in the main function to use options 2 or 3.

@greybeard I have updated my answer explaining usage of the non-default testing options and clarified the comments in the script.  I may add argparse command line options to improve usage ...

Commendable (in)code documentation.

As far as I know, the problem of "smallest circle enclosing a set of points" is interchangeable with the problem of "smallest circle enclosing some polygon defined by a sequence of vertices".
My standalone library precisely solves the first problem. It only depends on the Python standard library and no others. Source code is found at https://www.nayuki.io/page/smallest-enclosing-circle .
# Smallest enclosing circle - Library (Python)
# Copyright (c) 2020 Project Nayuki
# 
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
# 
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with this program (see COPYING.txt and COPYING.LESSER.txt).
# If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import math, random


# Data conventions: A point is a pair of floats (x, y). A circle is a triple of floats (center x, center y, radius).

# Returns the smallest circle that encloses all the given points. Runs in expected O(n) time, randomized.
# Input: A sequence of pairs of floats or ints, e.g. [(0,5), (3.1,-2.7)].
# Output: A triple of floats representing a circle.
# Note: If 0 points are given, None is returned. If 1 point is given, a circle of radius 0 is returned.
# 
# Initially: No boundary points known
def make_circle(points):
    # Convert to float and randomize order
    shuffled = [(float(x), float(y)) for (x, y) in points]
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    
    # Progressively add points to circle or recompute circle
    c = None
    for (i, p) in enumerate(shuffled):
        if c is None or not is_in_circle(c, p):
            c = _make_circle_one_point(shuffled[ : i + 1], p)
    return c


# One boundary point known
def _make_circle_one_point(points, p):
    c = (p[0], p[1], 0.0)
    for (i, q) in enumerate(points):
        if not is_in_circle(c, q):
            if c[2] == 0.0:
                c = make_diameter(p, q)
            else:
                c = _make_circle_two_points(points[ : i + 1], p, q)
    return c


# Two boundary points known
def _make_circle_two_points(points, p, q):
    circ = make_diameter(p, q)
    left  = None
    right = None
    px, py = p
    qx, qy = q
    
    # For each point not in the two-point circle
    for r in points:
        if is_in_circle(circ, r):
            continue
        
        # Form a circumcircle and classify it on left or right side
        cross = _cross_product(px, py, qx, qy, r[0], r[1])
        c = make_circumcircle(p, q, r)
        if c is None:
            continue
        elif cross > 0.0 and (left is None or _cross_product(px, py, qx, qy, c[0], c[1]) > _cross_product(px, py, qx, qy, left[0], left[1])):
            left = c
        elif cross < 0.0 and (right is None or _cross_product(px, py, qx, qy, c[0], c[1]) < _cross_product(px, py, qx, qy, right[0], right[1])):
            right = c
    
    # Select which circle to return
    if left is None and right is None:
        return circ
    elif left is None:
        return right
    elif right is None:
        return left
    else:
        return left if (left[2] <= right[2]) else right


def make_diameter(a, b):
    cx = (a[0] + b[0]) / 2
    cy = (a[1] + b[1]) / 2
    r0 = math.hypot(cx - a[0], cy - a[1])
    r1 = math.hypot(cx - b[0], cy - b[1])
    return (cx, cy, max(r0, r1))


def make_circumcircle(a, b, c):
    # Mathematical algorithm from Wikipedia: Circumscribed circle
    ox = (min(a[0], b[0], c[0]) + max(a[0], b[0], c[0])) / 2
    oy = (min(a[1], b[1], c[1]) + max(a[1], b[1], c[1])) / 2
    ax = a[0] - ox;  ay = a[1] - oy
    bx = b[0] - ox;  by = b[1] - oy
    cx = c[0] - ox;  cy = c[1] - oy
    d = (ax * (by - cy) + bx * (cy - ay) + cx * (ay - by)) * 2.0
    if d == 0.0:
        return None
    x = ox + ((ax*ax + ay*ay) * (by - cy) + (bx*bx + by*by) * (cy - ay) + (cx*cx + cy*cy) * (ay - by)) / d
    y = oy + ((ax*ax + ay*ay) * (cx - bx) + (bx*bx + by*by) * (ax - cx) + (cx*cx + cy*cy) * (bx - ax)) / d
    ra = math.hypot(x - a[0], y - a[1])
    rb = math.hypot(x - b[0], y - b[1])
    rc = math.hypot(x - c[0], y - c[1])
    return (x, y, max(ra, rb, rc))


_MULTIPLICATIVE_EPSILON = 1 + 1e-14

def is_in_circle(c, p):
    return c is not None and math.hypot(p[0] - c[0], p[1] - c[1]) <= c[2] * _MULTIPLICATIVE_EPSILON


# Returns twice the signed area of the triangle defined by (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2).
def _cross_product(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (x1 - x0) * (y2 - y0) - (y1 - y0) * (x2 - x0)

Example usage:
>>> import smallestenclosingcircle

>>> smallestenclosingcircle.make_circle([(2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)])

(1.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951)

I also provide other language ports: Java, TypeScript/JavaScript, C#, C++.

The return value of make_diameter() is not a diameter (and the radius is not computed from the point difference/diameter, which deserves explanation). I wish the code followed the Style Guide for Python Code.

The shapely python package has minimum_bounding_circle and minimum_bounding_radius functions.
First, find minimum enclosing circle using the minimum_bounding_circle function.  Then get circle center coordinates using the centroid method.  Third, find circle radius using minium_bounding_radius function.  Finally, plot polygon and enclosing circle using matplotlib:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely import minimum_bounding_radius, minimum_bounding_circle


p = Polygon([(2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)])

c = minimum_bounding_circle(p)
circle_coords = c.centroid.coords[0]
circle_radius = minimum_bounding_radius(c)
print(circle_coords, circle_radius)


# plot polygon and enclosing circle
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.plot(*p.exterior.xy, color="blue")
plt.plot(*c.exterior.xy, color="red")
plt.show()

This returns:
(1.0, 0.9999999999999999) 1.4142135623730954



This code was useful in testing the algorithm in my other answer.  The answer from @Timeless using openCV is probably faster than both of my answers.
Finally, their is similar functionality in GeoPandas.  See this GIS question: GeoPandas: Smallest Enclosing Circle.
